# How to remove horizontal space between images in a table

Tags: whitespace

Before I linked the images in the table to image galleries, there was no spaces between the images. I was able to remove the vertical spaces with `font-size:0;` but I can't seem to find a way to remove the horizontal spaces..

`

```
    <div class="center">        
            <table id="Table_01" width="960" height="603" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr><!--
                 --><td><ul class="gallery clearfix"></ul><!--
                    --> <div class="c1"><!--
                        --> <ul class="gallery clearfix"><!--
                        -->     <a href="img/photos/c1/c_1.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto [ch1]"><img src="img/maison/maison_01.png" width="644" height="253" alt=""></a><!--
                        --> </ul><!--
                    --> </div>
                        <div class="c1">
                            <ul class="gallery clearfix">
                                <a href="img/photos/c1/c_2.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto [ch1]"></a>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="c1">
                            <ul class="gallery clearfix">
                                <a href="img/photos/c1/c_3.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto [ch1]"></a>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="c1">
                            <ul class="gallery clearfix">
                                <a href="img/photos/c1/s_1.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto [ch1]"></a>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="c1">
                            <ul class="gallery clearfix">
                                <a href="img/photos/c1/s_2.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto [ch1]"></a>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </td><!--
                 --><td><!--
                    --> <div class="c2"><!--
                        --> <ul class="gallery clearfix"><!--
                        -->     <a href="img/photos/c2/c_1.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto [ch2]"><img src="img/maison/maison_02.png" width="316" height="253" alt=""></a><!--
                        --> </ul><!--
                    --> </div>
                        <div class="c2">
                            <ul class="gallery clearfix">
                                <a href="img/photos/c2/c_2.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto [ch2]"></a>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="c2">
                            <ul class="gallery clearfix">
                                <a href="img/photos/c2/c_3.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto [ch2]"></a>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="c2">
                            <ul class="gallery clearfix">
                                <a href="img/photos/c2/c_4.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto [ch2]"></a>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </td><!--
             --></tr><!--
             --><tr><!--
                --> <td><!--
                    --> <div class="bu"><!--
                        --> <ul class="gallery clearfix"><!--
                        -->     <a href="img/photos/bu/bu_1.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto [bu1]"><img src="img/maison/maison_03.png" width="644" height="121" alt=""></a><!--
                        --> </ul><!--
                    --> </div><!--
                --> </td><!--
                 --><td rowspan="2">
                        <div class="sal">
                            <ul class="gallery clearfix">
                                <a href="img/photos/sal/b_1.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto [sal]"><img src="img/maison/maison_04.png" width="316" height="350" alt=""></a>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="sal">
                            <ul class="gallery clearfix">
                                <a href="img/photos/sal/b_2.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto [sal]"></a>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="sal">
                            <ul class="gallery clearfix">
                                <a href="img/photos/sal/b_3.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto [sal]"></a>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </td><!--
             --></tr><!--
             --><tr><!--
                 --><td><!--
                    --> <div class="sej"><!--
                        --> <ul class="gallery clearfix"><!--
                        -->     <a href="img/photos/sej/s_1.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto [sej]"><img src="img/maison/maison_05.png" width="644" height="229" alt=""></a><!--
                        --> </ul><!--
                    --> </div>
                        <div class="sej">
                            <ul class="gallery clearfix">
                                <a href="img/photos/sej/s_2.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto [sej]"></a>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="sej">
                            <ul class="gallery clearfix">
                                <a href="img/photos/sej/s_3.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto [sej]"></a>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="sej">
                            <ul class="gallery clearfix">
                                <a href="img/photos/sej/s_4.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto [sej]"></a>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr><!--
        --> </table>
        </div>

</div>

<!-- PrettyPhoto SCRIPT -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("area[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();

            $(".gallery:first a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({animation_speed:'normal',slideshow:3000, autoplay_slideshow: false});
            $(".gallery:gt(0) a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({animation_speed:'fast',slideshow:10000, hideflash: true});

            $("#custom_content a[rel^='prettyPhoto']:first").prettyPhoto({
                custom_markup: '<div id="map_canvas" style="width:260px; height:265px"></div>',
                changepicturecallback: function(){ initialize(); }
            });

            $("#custom_content a[rel^='prettyPhoto']:last").prettyPhoto({
                custom_markup: '<div id="bsap_1259344" class="bsarocks bsap_d49a0984d0f377271ccbf01a33f2b6d6"></div><div id="bsap_1237859" class="bsarocks bsap_d49a0984d0f377271ccbf01a33f2b6d6" style="height:260px"></div><div id="bsap_1251710" class="bsarocks bsap_d49a0984d0f377271ccbf01a33f2b6d6"></div>',
                changepicturecallback: function(){ _bsap.exec(); }
            });
        });
</script>
```

CSS:

`.center {display: block;font-size: 0;max-width:1100px;margin-top: -30px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;}`

result: http://www.simoncokes.ovh/mais.html

Excuse me for the mess, I'm only a beginner/noob/learner !

Comment: There's a horizontal space between 1st and 2nd images, and between 3rd and 4th images. So I believe between the "td's" in each "tr".. if that makes sense!

Comment: I may be doing something wrong, but I can't make this work.. :(

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
td, th {
  border: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

tr {
  border: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

img {
  display: block;
}
```

Also, set table with this attributes:

```
cellspacing = "0"  cellpadding = "0"
```

It should work

Comment: I'm not sure what the "s" means in your answer ?
I tried border and padding in the CSS, but that won't work apparently..

Comment: I can't seem to make this work.. thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi @Simon check edited post, this should cover all options

Comment: try adding cellspacing = "0"  cellpadding = "0" to the table

Comment: That was in there already, and i added to each image aswell, but still won't do it! Thanks for your precious help anyway!